# Javascript HTML PAGE_iDs

Tags: php, javascript, html, cordova

Can someone please tell me why is it when the selected option is not changing to the page id i have it for? No matter what it just reloads to the home page.

```
 <form>
  <select name="pageid" onchange="window.location.href=this.form.pageid.options[this.form.pageid.selectedIndex].value">
  <option id="">Choose a page</option>
  <option value="?id=page19">Page 19</option>
  <option value="?id=page1">Page 1</option>
  <option value="?id=page9">Page 9</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

I am new to this so please help. For example if user selects "Page 1" it doesnt take them to page 1 it just reloads the current page.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the problem, but `this.form.pageid` is the same as just `this`.

Comment: Does it work if you go to one of those URLs by hand?

Comment: i think problem is in your php

Comment: You can just reduce to: `window.location.href=this.value`

Comment: This appears to already be working. Try this fiddle, and watch the network traffic (chrome dev tools, for example) while selecting an option from the form: http://jsfiddle.net/ZbrpX/

Comment: Did you try window.location instead of window.location.href

Comment: You can reduce it further to just `window.location=this.value`

Answer (score 1):

Change your `onchange` method to

```
onchange="redirectToLink()"
```

And have this function in your JavaScript

```
function redirectToLink() {
window.location.href=window.location.href+this.form.pageid.options[this.form.pageid.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
$('#YourID').change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).val();
});
```

If you want menu to display the current page you are on you can write a conditional.

```
<option value="<?= theURL ?>" <?=($slug == 'pageName')?'selected="selected"':''?>>pageName</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works correctly ([jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xta7Z/1/)), however you can write `onchange` simpler:

```
<select name="pageid" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
```

As your pages is something like these:

```
// ?id=page1
// ?id=page2
// ?id=page3
```

These are actually the **current page**, with a **QueryString**. 
So you don't see any changes, until you are controlling QueryString
in your server side language:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo "On the page {$_GET['id']}";
}

?>
```